# Uber Eats delivery options - new COVID related feature

Tags: uber-api

Uber Eats introduced a new feature - delivery options such as: "direct delivery", "leave at door", "meeting outside". How can I access it using UberEats API? I can't see it documented https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/references/api/v2/eats-order-order_id-get